# How to find the statistical significance of temperature and sea surface pressure on the precipitation for a period of 10 years on a place using r

Tags: r, statistics

```
x1 <- read.csv(file = "Precipitation2.csv", skip = 0, head = TRUE, sep=",", quote="")
JAN<-x1$JAN
pressure_jan <- JAN[1:11]
temp_jan<-JAN[12:22]
rain_jan <- JAN[23:33]
```

> I have three variables containing the data of a particular place  for the period of 10
> years. The variables are at regular intervals. So how can I find which
> variable(pressure or temperature) is more significant for the
> precipitation to occur.
> OR I'm looking for the variable which has stronger correlation with precipitation

Comment: You can run `cor(x1)` and see which matrix entry is greater.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it appears to focus on data analysis or statistics and not a practical programming question as defined in the [help/on-topic].